# How can i write a function, which if it's parameter is a node collection, executes for all node elements in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

It was very confusing, how to ask this question (especially, with half knowledge of english).
So what i want to do is, to write a function what detects if it's parameter is a single node, or a node collection, and depending on that, it gets the data of the node/nodes. But it's easier to show, than describe. (the explanations are in the comments inside the code) And i want to appologize for language mistakes in english and in javascript too, and the long explanation of my problem.

```js
var e, eH;
function x(y){
  e = y;
  eH = e.offsetHeight;
};
var ps = document.querySelectorAll("p");
x(ps);
e.style.top = `${eH}px`;
```

just for an example, i want to set the top style property to the element's height, but the ps is a node collection.

```js
var e, eH, i = 0;
function x(y){
  e = y;
  eH = e.offsetHeight;
  howmany(e)
};

function howmany(z){
e = z;
if (e[i] !== undefined){
  for (i; i<e.length; i++){
    e = e[i]
    }
  };
  
var ps = document.querySelectorAll("p");
x(ps);
e.style.top = `${eH}px`;
```

that was my first idea, but i know, in this way it will never work

```js
var i,a;
function fun(e){
 i = 0;
 a = e;
if (e[i] === undefined){
 a+=1
 }
else{
 for (i; i<e.length; i++){
     a[i]+=1;
     }
 }
};
var x = [1,2,3,4,5];
fun(x);
```

then i tried with numbers, it works. But not solution for my problem.

```js
var e, eH, i = 0;
function x(y, whattodo){
  e = y;
  eH = e.offsetHeight;
  c = whattodo
  howmany(e, c)
};

function howmany(z, v){
e = z;
if (e[i] !== undefined){
  for (i; i<e.length; i++){
    e[i].v
    }
  };
 
 var ps = document.querySelectorAll("p"),
 var wtd = style.top = `${eH}px`;
 x(ps, wtd);
```

if my goal is, to set especially one property on one or multiple elements, this will be great, but it isn't my goal.
     my goal is that when i call the function, with a node collection, i can "control" not one element from the collection, and not the collection, but every single element in the collection. 
     since i think it's impossible to describe my problem this way, let me show a real example. I'll show my code:

```js
 var elem, celElem, elemTop, elemMag, elemBot, elemCent, winTop, winMag, winBot, winCent;
function getElem(el, cEl){
 elem = el,
 celElem = cEl,
 elemTop = 0,
 elemMag = elem.offsetHeight,
 elemBot = elemTop+elemMag,
 elemCent = elemTop+(elemMag/2),
 winTop = window.pageYOffset,
 winMag = window.innerHeight,
 winBot = winTop+winMag,
 winCent = winTop+(winMag/2),
 if (celElem === undefined){celElem = elem};
 topMag(elem);
};

function topMag(x){
 elem = x;
 if (getComputedStyle(elem).position === "fixed"){
  elemTop = elem.offsetTop;
 }
 else{
  do{
   elemTop += elem.offsetTop;
   elem = elem.offsetParent;
  }
  while(elem != "[object HTMLBodyElement]");
  elem = x;
 }
};
var targetElem = document.querySelectorAll("p");
var nagyElemCent = -Math.abs((winCent-elemCent)/((elemMag+winMag)/2))+1;
getElem(targetElem);
elem.style.opacity = nagyElemCent;
```

i hope this example better describes my problem. What i want is, when i set the elem in the last line of code, the elem means all the paragraphs. I have many pre-coded numbers like nagyElemCent, but most of the times them need to be modified to get what i want.

Answer (score 1):

To know whether or not a value is a node or a node collection, you can check to see if it has a `length` property on it.

Inside of the function, if you check and have received a single node, turn that single node into an array and act on it that way, so you only have to check once if it's an array, and don't have to worry about it for the rest of the function.

```
function doSomething(nodes) {
  if (!('length' in nodes)) {
    nodes = [nodes]
  }

  nodes.forEach(node => {
    // do something w/ each node
  })
}
```

Comment: Can i ask you please, to explain your solution within my last block of code?